# Can i use "int" instead of "extern" int in another file?

Tags: c

I had read that if I want to use a global variable in another C file,I should precede the data type with the access specifier **extern** like that:

```
File One                             File Two
int x, y;                            extern int x, y;
char ch;                             extern char ch;
int main(void)                       void func22(void)
{                                     {
/* ... */                              x = y / 10;
}                                     }
void func1(void)                      void func23(void)
{                                     {
x = 123;                               y = 10;
}                                     }
```

and by mistake in file two I don't declare x, y as they are. I declared them as `int x` and `int y` and I wait the compiler to display an error of redefinition of variables x and y, but the code runs without any errors.

for example:

**File One**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global = 1000;  /** declare global variable called 
                       global **/

int main(){

print();

return 0;
}
```

**File Two**

```
int global;   /** here I don't use the extern keyword **/

void print(void){

global = 100;

printf("\n global = %d",global);

return;

}
```

the result is : `global = 100`

**The program is compiled and linked without any error**

So my question is: Is `extern` specifier is redundant here ?!

Comment: no there is no compile error

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy: Right, got it - you *expected* a compiler error (or linker error?!), but didn't get one...

Comment: YES, so, can you help me in that problem?! @KerrekSB

Comment: See the linked duplicate question. I think that explains it pretty well.

Comment: @Yu Hao can you answer this question please.

Comment: @pNre check the code above in my question

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any error because the compiler does not check the type nor the existence of the external variable.
It is in the linking phase that the linker searches in the object files for a reference to a symbol named `x` (or `y`).

Comment: so is it a redundant here ?!!

can u explain to me more about what the compiler do here ?

Comment: It is not redundant, the `extern` keyword tells the compiler there's a symbol named `x` somewhere else then the linker searches for this symbol's definition in the objects files being linked. If there's no `extern` the symbols are redefined leading to a linking error (duplicate symbol named x)

Comment: but there is no linking error also!